# How do I make a JS script continue to run after navigation (google chrome console)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Say I have a simple script

```
var i = 0;
test();
function test() {
     console.log(i++);
     setTimeout(test, 1000);
}
```

I put it in a Google Chrome console. How do I make it continue to run after the page navigates to another (should continue to print out numbers when browsing the web)?

Maybe save the variable 'i' in onbeforeunload() function, and launch a new script with that saved variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make it continue to run after the page navigates to another

you can't, the script cannot continue on another page, it's the browser that runs the javascript in the page, and that will stop it when moving to another page.

> (or) should continue to print out numbers when browsing the web?

you have yourself answered this. You can certainly save the counter in localstorage and resume counting on the next page, provided this next page contains the same or similar script and the logic to restore the counter from localStorage.

Or, you can move part of this logic to a server-side script.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this script is an example and displaying numbers is not really what you want to do.

If you are looking for something to run script even when you have left the browser, I suggest you take a look at [Service workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/).

If you want more resources, you can check Jake Archibald's blog. He is a chrome developer and he is always talking about service workers. An introduction [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/using-serviceworker-today/).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any good suggestions posted already for what I was trying to do but I came up with something that worked for me. I wanted to add a navigation element on the page and not have it go away after navigating. This was on a website that was not managed by me. I removed the innerHtml of the body of the page, added an iframe and pointed it at the page I was on, set it to 100% width and height and removed the border. Then I could navigate within the iframe, but still have my script function run in a set timeout to add the navigation element back to the page after it navigated. Something like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = ''
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('id', 'iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.setAttribute('src', window.location.href);
iframe.style.height = "100%";
iframe.style.width = "100%";
iframe.style.border = "0";
function addContent(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
    elementToAddTo = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('my-element-id')];
    contentToAdd = document.createElement('div');
    contentToAdd.innerHTML = `<p>My new content</p>`
    elementToAddTo.insertBefore(contentToAdd, elementToAddTo.childNodes[0]);
    }, 1000);
}
addContent()
```

Then in that new content somewhere I had an onchange event which would navigate and call the addContent function by saying window.top.addContent();

```
onchange="window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/(param1=.*)/, 'param1='+myNewParamValue); window.top.addContent();">
```

I Understand this approach makes a lot of assumptions about what you're trying to do and maybe it is only working for me because I'm only changing a param value, but I want to leave this hear in case it helps somebody trying to figure out how to do something similar.